# SharePoint Designer Workflow should create Calendar Event

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-calendar

I've created a workflow, that handles vacation requests. After requesting via a SharePoint list it send an email to a supervisor who should approve or reject and once it is approved the workflow should create a calendar event to visualize the vacation. So far so good.

Problem occurs when it comes to the creation of the calendar event. Vacation for one day is no problem. But when the user request more than one day the last vacation day is still missing. For instance: If i am requesting time off from 19.01.2017 to 20.01.2017 only for the 19.01.2017 an event is created.

Forcing the workflow to create an All-Day event makes the problem even more suspicious. Taking the example above he will create vacation from the 18.01.2017-19.01.2017.

How can i make sure the workflow creates the right calendar events?

Answer (score 3):

create new calendar event, and make All Day Event to Yes automatically.

Please set All Day Event field to value 1 when create new calendar event in workflow.

In your case start time will be 19.01.2017
End time time 20.01.2017

[image]

Comment: As mentioned above: This works BUT it moves the vacation to one day earlier. For instance: Vacation requested for: 18.01. - 19.01. Vacation in calendar 17.01.-18.01.

Comment: try to capture only date not time, so all day event will take entire day.

Comment: I've tried to capture only the date without the time, but when it comes to the event-creation the time is set again to 00:00. And that is what causes the problem. If the begin-date is 01.01.2017 00:00 SharePoint seems to interpret this as 31.12.2016 00:00. 

Is there a possibility to change the time?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to replicate the issue as you have mentioned. See my updated  workflow step 
[image]

Corresponding result in calendar list 
[image]